# I want to assign a class to the select drop downs when they are open or close using Angular 2 without using local Flag

Tags: angular, select, drop-down-menu, tags

I was trying to give a class to the select drop downs when its open or close using Angular 2 but not able to that. I know using local flag I can do it but don't want to use local flags as flags are always hard to maintain.Any solutions?

Comment: Share your code as well to justify your efforts

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
panelOpen: boolean - Whether or not the overlay panel is open.
```

in combination with

```
@Input()
panelClass: string | string[] | Set<string> | { [key: string]: any; }

Classes to be passed to the select panel. Supports the same syntax as ngClass.
```

taken from the [docs](https://material.angular.io/components/select/api)

Comment: ah you're right, maybe i still had that in my head from a previous question :)